# convert post array to single quote using php

Tags: php

I have this form post in array:

```
array([tags] => test,test1,test2,test3,test4);
```

I need to print each tags with Single Quote `'` and separation with `,` like this :

```
'test','test1','test2','test3','test4'
```

how do can i create and print this output?!

Comment: Because the problem is trivial and you needlessly used `?!`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$tags = explode(',', $array['tags']);
$quoted_tags = array_map(function($x) { return "'$x'"; }, $tags);
$string = implode(',', $quoted_tags);
```

If you'll be storing this in a database, don't forget to escape the tags, too.

Comment: You don't need to escape anything when storing things in databases. Always use parameterised queries.

Comment: Actually, this looks like it's actually intended to be used in a `WHERE col IN ($string)` list. Doing that with parametrized queries is tricky, because of the variable length.

Comment: Then you generate a list of comma-separated question marks. Or if you use PostgreSQL you bind an array.

Comment: @Barmar:Right on, i need to this for `WHERE col IN ($string)`. useful code.

Answer (score 3):

```
$tags = explode(',', $array['tags']);
echo implode(',', array_map(function($tag) { return "'$tag'"; }, $tags));
```

Comment: I think you're adding too many quotes. You've got quotes in the function, and also in the `implode` argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newtags="'".str_replace(",","','",$array['tags'])."'";
```

Comment: This yields `''` for the empty array, whereas it should yield the empty string.

Comment: I think OP can check empty array.Even he did not said what will be the output for empty array.Also I am confused why he asked this simple question.